# Standing for whole of Lecha Dodi

Tags: minhag, provenance, standing-sitting, shabbat-songs, kabbalat-shabbat

Certain families in my shul have the minhag to stand for the entire Lecha Dodi.  I asked them why, but they do not know the source of the minhag.

Does anyone know what the source of this minhag is?

Comment: Offhand, I think the main reason is to simulate the honor given to the Shabbat "Queen". It is customary to stand before royalty.

Comment: welcoming the shabbos malka. why sit for lecha dodi?

Comment: @Dude:  Why say it at all?  Most of Kabbalat Shabbat is a relatively modern innovation.  As the Artscroll Siddur says, Mizmor Shir L'Yom HaShabbat is where it originally began.

Comment: @Ask613 how are you defining modern innovation? Also Kabbalat Shabbat with some few minor differences has been accepted by everyone making it a very strong minhag yisroel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Kovetz Bais Aharon V'Yisrael 66 - page 97](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13561&st=&pgnum=98&hilite=) says the source for standing at Lecha Dodi is the [Tikunei Shabbos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43147&st=&pgnum=13) which mentions that one should stand Lekovod Shabbos Kodesh while saying the Lecha Dodi. It is also mentioned in Kitzur H'shla.

They go on to mention that the Sar Shalom M'Belz said that when Rabbi Shlomo Alkabatz composed the Lecha Dodi he requested that people stand while saying it.

Comment: +1 Is it just my imagination or doors it seem that mainly 'American' or Modern Orthodox are the ones standing the whole time? It's definitely not Chassidish or Yeshivish. The few sfardi minyanim ive been at Friday night night also didnt stand, but I can't generalize for all their communities based on that. Anyone else have input?

Comment: @user6591: In my linked answer it mentions that in Telz they stand for Lecha Dodi. It also would indicate that Belz does.

Comment: I see. Seems to be a yotzeh min haklal, but definitely noteworthy. There is also the Chasidish(?) Minhag to stand up by 'Yamin'. In the footnote there. Interesting where things like this come from.

Comment: @user6591 Lubavitch stands for Lecha Dodi, although it's unclear if it's just a prat in standing the whole Kabbalas Shabbos.

Comment: @Shmuel you mean lubavitch stands from Lichu Niranina and on?

Comment: @user6591 *they say* the Lubavitcher Rebbe did.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin in tehilas Hashem sidur it says to stand from mizmor ledovid until after barchu

Answer (score 6):

The Aderet Rav Eliyahu David Rabinowitz-Teomim basing himself on the Gemara in Bava Kama 32b and in Shabbos (119a) implies that the Lecha Dodi should be said while standing. The Gemara says:

> :רבי ינאי מתעטף **וקאי** ואמר בואי כלה בואי כלה

Rav Yanai  was "wrapped and **standing** saying Come queen Come Queen"

[Quoted Aderet](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20408&st=&pgnum=188):

> ואנו נוהגין לעמוד לעשות  דוגמא כמו שמקבל פני אדם גדול. **ובאמת הוא תלמוד
>   ערוך בשבת (קיט, א) ר״ח מעטף  וקאי אפניא דמעלי שבתא וכו׳**. ובב״ק (לב, א)
>   יש קצת שינוי מבשבת שם.

Comment: This is a proof for Boi Kallah. Everyone stands for Boi Kallah. The question asked is concerning standing for the whole Lecha Dodi. How does he extend it for the entire lecha dodi

Comment: That's what the Aderes says, I saw it quoted in the shearim metzuyanim behalacha

Comment: Do you have exact mekor?

Comment: Not right now. But I'm sure th smh bringsvit

Comment: The Aderet says something similar to this in *Eileh Ya'amdu* and *T'filas David*. What he says is that the custom to stand can be explained by that gemara ("ונראה שמה שעומדים באמירת פיוט לכה דודי הוא מן הך דרבי (חנינא) [ינאי] קאי"). So he didn't quite say to stand because of that gemara so much as that this gemara can explain the practice of standing. As far as the שערים מצויינים בהלכה, I would expect to see this mentioned [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14622&pgnum=76) if anywhere, but I don't see it there. Do you recall precisely where you saw the Aderet cited?

Comment: Link to the Aderet's remark in *V'Eileh Ya'amdu* [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20408&st=&pgnum=188).

Comment: @Fred the Shearim Metzuyanim Behalacha on Bava Kama 32b

Answer (score 2):

In the Machzor Polin MiKol HaShanah,it says that the first 6 tehillim of Kabollas Shabbos are kneged a different day of the working week, therefore they should be said sitting. Lecha Dodi is kneged Shabbos therefore it says to stand l'kovod Shabbos.